# How to make passportjs local username be case insensitive?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Right now I'm using passportjs (local) for authentication on my site, but the username field is case sensitive, is there a way to change this? I thought about making the username all lowercase at the moment of registration, but that doesn't seem like a very efficient choice and still doesn't let me make log in case insensitive.

```
router.post("/login", middleware.isNotLoggedIn, passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "",
failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res){
    res.redirect("back");
});
```

Comment: are you using some kind of database/ persistent storage?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be efficient to lowercase the username at the moment of registration? It's probably one of the _most_ efficient methods.

Comment: @staar I'm storing the information in mongodb

Comment: @robertklep how do I change the parameters from whatever case they're in at the moment of log in to lowercase and then send it to passport.authenticate?

Comment: @Danyx you do that right before you query the database (in the Passport strategy verification handler).

Comment: @robertklep you mean that would require me to change the passportjs code? Or do you mean as in another method that I have to run before the query?

Comment: @Danyx your code must somewhere use `new LocalStrategy(...)`. That's where you lowercase the username that got passed, right before you query the database to check if the user credentials are valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122932/discussion-between-danyx-and-robertklep).

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi's answer should be marked as the correct answer for future users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem myself. Seems like passport should have an official answer to this. Simplest way it to make a middleware. This middleware would need to be in TWO places. First in the register function so that the username is saved in lowercase. Then in the Login function as shown below for an example. Good luck!

```
  function usernameToLowerCase(req, res, next){
            req.body.username = req.body.username.toLowerCase();
            next();
        }
  router.post("/login", usernameToLowerCase, passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function (req, res) {
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

@robertklep was on to the right idea by suggesting a new LocalStrategy(...).  Notice the `new RegExp(username, "i")` to make the comparison case-insensitive.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
   //User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
     User.getUserByUsername(new RegExp("^" + username + "$", "i"), function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }
    ...
```